# changing text color on hover - jasper

Tags: css, jasperserver

I've gone through a few different examples in the forums and can't figure this one out. I have a report element that links to a sub report. The color for this element is by design set to RED. I am attempting to modify the CSS to create a blue underline upon hover and that is working correctly with this code:

```
    ._jrHyperLink:hover         { text-decoration: underline;
                        color: #0563c1 ;
}
```

but I also want to also on hover change the font color to #0563c1. I tried this

```
._jrHyperLink:hover         { 
                        color: #0563c1 ;
}
```

and

```
 ._jrHyperLink:hover         { 
                        color: #0563c1 !important ;
}
```

neither have resulted in changing the default color.

the report code that defines this report element is below

```
<td rowspan="3" style="white-space: nowrap; text-indent: 0px; vertical-align: middle;text-align: right;" tabindex="0" class="subfocus">
```

18,036

which translates to this

```
element.style {
    font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FF0000;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2578125;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

in case any of this is relevant. Just not sure what else I can try.

Comment: the element has the _jrHyperLink class? the question ins't very well explained

Answer (score 0):

CSS rules operate based on cascade and specificity, so if you are saying that things with class `subfocus` are supposed to have a rule of `color: red;` when you hover over their parent with class of `_jrHyperLink`, then declaring a change in `color` on the parent won't override rules on the child.

If you need to trigger the state change when hovering over a parent element, in this case something with class `._jrHyperLink`, you could do two rules - one for the underline (since that's styling for the parent element) and one for the text color of the child:

```
._jrHyperLink:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

._jrHyperLink:hover .subfocus {
  color: #0563c1;
}
```

As long as your CSS doesn't have multiple-level nested rules setting that `.subfocus` element's color, this should override it properly.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure what do you mean. what element has `_jrHyperLink` class ?

Undestand from your code said that your target element is inside `<td class="subfocus">` , if that's the case, you can try this instead

```
.subfocus:hover{ 
    color: #0563c1 !important ;
}
```